# Display a view of users who purchased a product

Tags: commerce

Ok I have been smashing my head into a wall for the last week trying to figure this out.

1. I have setup a content type called event.
2. I setup two product types called Adult Ticket and Childs Ticket
3. I referenced the tickets on the content type event.
4. Created a number of events which all use the same two product types (Adult Ticket and Child Ticket)
5. I have only had users purchase one of those events.
6. Setup a view based on transaction and setup references so the user fields can be displayed and also the title of the event and all is displayed in a table.
7. I have setup a filter to display the event (node) titles so that in the view the user can switch between events with the hope that it would only show users that purchased a ticket for that event however it shows all users who purchased them for any event as it appears it is doing it based on the product not the node.

How can I overcome this and only show users who purchased a product from a specific node?

Any help would be great

[image]

Comment: need more info, specifically how did you set up your relationships and filters. it'd be best if you can add a screenshot of your view configuration (ie admin/structure/views/view/YOURVIEW/edit) with the advanced column on the right expanded